# Unable to correctly map index using the index template in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing

I have a index template created as below

```
PUT _template/es-logs
{
  "index_patterns": ["es-*"],
  "template": {
    "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 2,
    "number_of_replicas": 1
      },
    "mappings": {
      "_source": {
        "enabled": false
      },
      "properties": {
       "conn_state" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "content_length" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "content_type" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "createdDate" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "dst_ip" : {
          "type" : "ip"
        },
        "dst_port" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "duration" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "history" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "local_orig" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "missed_bytes" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "orig_bytes" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "orig_ip_bytes" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "orig_pkts" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "protocol" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "resp_bytes" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "resp_ip_bytes" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "resp_pkts" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "service" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        },
        "src_ip" : {
          "type" : "ip"
        },
        "src_port" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "timestamp" : {
          "type" : "date",
          "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"
        },
        "uid" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However when I try to use lambda function to transfer data from my s3 bucket into ES, my index is not using template for the mapping. Instead, it showing all the fields mapped as 'text'. My index name is 'es-logs-2020-5-22'.

Any help to resolve this issue is appreciated. Thanks